# Get controller receives JSON with List<String> as null in Spring JPA

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, postman

When I'm posting a new entity through Postman everything works fine and I get this as an answer:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "ingredients": [
        "Eggs",
        "Oil"
    ]
}
```

But when I'm trying to get the existing entities in the database, the List< String > ingredients is returned as "null":

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "ingredients": null
    }
]
```

Here is my model:

```
package com.petie.weeklyrecipesschedule.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @Embedded
    private List<String> ingredients;

    protected Recipe() {}

    public Recipe(String name, List<String> ingredients) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    //Getters and setters
    //toString()
}
```

My Repository

```
package com.petie.weeklyrecipesschedule.repository;

import com.petie.weeklyrecipesschedule.model.Recipe;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipe, Long> {
}
```

And my controller

```
package com.petie.weeklyrecipesschedule.controller;

import com.petie.weeklyrecipesschedule.model.Recipe;
import com.petie.weeklyrecipesschedule.repository.RecipeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/recipes")
public class RecipeController {

    @Autowired
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    public RecipeController(RecipeRepository recipeRepository) {
        this.recipeRepository = recipeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    List<Recipe> getAll() {
        return recipeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    Recipe newRecipe(@RequestBody Recipe recipe) {
        return recipeRepository.save(recipe);
    }
}
```

As far as dependencies go, I'm using Spring Web, Spring Jpa, and H2 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `@ElementCollection`:

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "recipe_ingredients", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"))
@Column(name = "ingredient_name")
private List<String> ingredients;
```

> The JPA annotation `@Embedded` is used to embed a type into another entity.

*Note: In addition, you don't need to send an `id` in your post request, it will be created automatically.*